# How can i make an edge wear mask in eevee?

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, procedural

Is there a way to make a worn edge effect in eevee with nodes and procedural textures? I know it can be done in cycles with pointiness, bevel or ambient occlusion node but those seem to work only in cycles and not in eevee.
I've heard about using cycles to create the mask, then bake it as an image and use it later in eevee as mask but i was wondering if there was a faster way to do it directly in eevee without having to bake.

Comment: Materials should be the same in both Eevee and Cycles. What about your material doesn't work in Eevee? Have you made sure to enable ambient occlusion in the eevee settings?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that's a problem with node compatibility between the two rendering engines, if you google it others say the same. Maybe they will fix this in the next updates, at least i hope so because those nodes are so useful for procedural texturing. I guess i will have to keep baking everytime in cycles until the developers find a fix, but i will leave this open, maybe someone knows how to achieve the same effect with different nodes.